# Change ASP.NET ReportViewer Toolbar Height

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer, vb.net-2010

I was asked to make ReportViewer Toolbar Easier to be seen(make Height and Icons larger).

Is this possible? All the code I have seen so far hide or show icons on toolbar .

Comment: You can  [change the CSS](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7e4478fb-932c-4762-b271-fc05afe95add/change-reportviewer-style?forum=sqlreportingservices).

Comment: @John Wu : can you please elaborate?

Comment: Did you click the link?

Comment: If you are refering to rldc CSS I looked at it but could not anything related to toolbar